# Jquery having trouble positioning images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, position, preloader

Follow on from:

[Javascript wait for image to load before calling Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943495/javascript-wait-for-image-to-load-before-calling-ajax)

```
function initResources() {

    var newImage;
    for (i = 0; i < resourceData.length; i++) {

        // Create the image
        newImage = $('<img alt="Big" id="imgA' + i + '" class="mediaImg" width="' + Math.round(resourceData[i][2] * currentScale) + '" height="' + Math.round(resourceData[i][3] * currentScale) + '" />');

        newImage.load(function() {

            alert(i);

            // Position
            $('#imgA' + i).position().top(Math.round(resourceData[i][5] * currentScale));
            $('#imgA' + i).position().left(Math.round(resourceData[i][4] * currentScale));

        });
        newImage[0].src = uploadFolder + '/' + imgData[resourceData[i][1]][1];
        $('#thePage').append(newImage);
    }
}
```

I have an array of images.  When the page is loaded initially from the server, this function loops through all the images and places them on the page.

This function is also called when the scale of the page changes.  The scaling function clears the HTML and redraws everything with the scale multiplier.

The problem with this function, is that it always alerts resourceData.length, which is the end of the loop.  I need to somehow pass data to the load function, so that when the image does finally load, it is referencing the correct ID/i.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a single `i` variable which is shared among all of your callbacks.

Since the callbacks execute asynchronously, they will all execute after the loop finishes, when `i` is `length`.

You need to put the loop body into a separate function that takes `i` as a parameter.
This way, each `load` callback will use a separate `i` variable (the function parameter), which will never change.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) loop to create the closure (into which that index is it's *own* variable, not shared) you need...and the [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) call needs a bit of change as well, you should use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) here which takes an object, like this:

```
function initResources() {
    var newImage;
    $.each(resourceData, function(i, data) {
       newImage = $('<img alt="Big" id="imgA' + i + '" class="mediaImg" width="' + Math.round(data[2] * currentScale) + '" height="' + Math.round(data[3] * currentScale) + '" />');
       newImage.load(function() {
            $(this).css({ top: Math.round(data[5] * currentScale), 
                         left: Math.round(data[4] * currentScale) });
       });
       newImage[0].src = uploadFolder + '/' + imgData[data[1]][1];
       $('#thePage').append(newImage);
    });
}
```

You can shorten this up more, but it'll be no more efficient.  Keep in mine that inside the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event handler you can refer to the element the handler is for with `this`, no need to select it again.

Comment: If you added a parameter to the `$.each()` callback you could get the value of `resourceData[i]` without having to dig through the array every time.

Comment: @gnarf - good point - it won't matter for small arrays but does look much cleaner....I also didn't notice that markdown totally screwed some array values there - thought *something* looked off, fixed now.